# How to find specific records between two date date

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a Gigantic table to save lots of logs from the beginning of time with this format:

```
==========================================================
| Name | Log                      | Date (type datetime) |
----------------------------------------------------------
| Bob  | {Some:[sort,of,json]}    | 1-May-2013 09:12:45  |
| Josh | {Another:[sort,of,json]} | 1-May-2013 09:13:45  |
| Fred | {Yada:[yada,yada,yada]}  | 1-May-2013 09:14:45  |
| Josh | {Ahoy:[whee,whee,whee]}  | 1-May-2013 09:15:45  |
| Lucy | {Ahem:[blagh,blgh,blgh]} | 1-May-2013 09:16:45  |
| Bob  | {Chih:[aw,ew,ow]}        | 2-May-2013 09:12:45  |
..........................................................
| Fred | {Cheh:[saw,sew,sow]}     | 1-May-2014 09:12:45  |   
| Bob  | {Chah:[waw,wew,wow]}     | 1-May-2014 09:15:45  |   
==========================================================
```

Now, given two datetimes, I need to grab one log for each person between those datetimes (any log within that time will do, but preferably the earliest within those two datetimes).

Here's a query I've tried but it still take too long

```
select * 
from ( select Name, 
              Log, 
              rank() over (partition by Name order by Date asc) ranks 
        from Table ) alias 
 where ranks = 1
```

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table? What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Could you post an execution plan?

Comment: There's an index on Date column. As for DBMS, it's planned to be used in a few different DBMS, so I try to avoid solution to specific DBMS.

Comment: I ask because the ideal index for this would be on `Date` and `Name` with Log included as a non key column to avoid the key lookup, but not all DBMS support non key columns. Aside from adding a where clause to filter between the specified dates your query would not need to change. Or do you have a primary key on the table?

Comment: @GarethD: what exactly do you mean with "non key columns"? user3148690: your example query does not include a where condition to limit the data to that between the "two datetimes" so the index on that column won't help.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Where the column data is included in the index leaf along with the clustered index pointer, but does not actually form part of the index. e.g. In SQL Server - `CREATE INDEX IX_Name ON Table (Date, Name) INCLUDE (Log)` - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use BETWEEN condition but inside of subquery

```
   select * 
    from ( select Name, 
                  Log, 
                  rank() over (partition by Name order by Date asc) ranks 
            from Table 
            WHERE Date BETWEEN @DateBegin AND @DateEnd     
    ) alias 
     where ranks = 1
```

To run it faster you have to create indexes on `Name` and `Date` fields

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `BETWEEN`

```
   SELECT * 
        FROM ( 
               SELECT Name, Log,
                      rank() OVER (partition by Name ORDER by Date ASC) ranks
                      FROM Table 
                      WHERE Date BETWEEN '2012-04-01 02:00:00′ AND '2012-04-20 02:00:00′
             ) alias 

            WHERE ranks = 1;
```

You have maybe to create `INDEX` on field you are using to accelerate the executing of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT    *
FROM      [YourTable]
WHERE     [YourDate] BETWEEN '08-15-2011 02:00:00' AND '08-16-2011 02:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information that you provided, I have give a generic example:

```
SELECT    *
FROM      [YourTable]
WHERE     [Your Date] BETWEEN '1-May-2013 02:00:00' AND '2-May-2013 02:00:00'
ORDER BY [yourDate] DESC
```